# which flatbed scanner are supported in 12.04 and abow

Tags: scanner

I have use **12.04** and And above Ubuntu OS...
But i have faced this problem is only two flatbed scanner is support in Ubuntu like **cannon LID 110 & HP-G2410**,
So any alternate scanner are supported our UBUNTU OS..?

Answer (score 0):

From the `sane` `man` page (`man sane`):

```
trusty (7) sane.7.gz
Provided by: libsane-common_1.0.23-3ubuntu1_i386 bug

NAME
       sane - Scanner Access Now Easy: API for accessing scanners

DESCRIPTION
       SANE  is  an  application  programming  interface  (API)  that provides
       standardized  access  to  any  raster  image  scanner   hardware.   The
       standardized  interface  makes it possible to write just one driver for
       each scanner  device  instead  of  one  driver  for  each  scanner  and
       application.

       While  SANE  is  primarily targeted at a UNIX environment, the standard
       has been carefully designed to make it possible to implement the API on
       virtually any hardware or operating system.

       This  manual page provides a summary of the information available about
       SANE.

       If you have trouble getting your scanner detected,  read  the  PROBLEMS
       section.

TERMINOLOGY
       An  application that uses the SANE interface is called a SANE frontend.
       A driver that implements the SANE interface is called a  SANE  backend.
       A  meta  backend  provides  some  means  to  manage  one  or more other
       backends.

SOFTWARE PACKAGES
       The package `sane-backends' contains a lot of  backends,  documentation
       (including the SANE standard), networking support, and the command line
       frontend  `scanimage'.   The  frontends   `xscanimage',   `xcam',   and
       `scanadf'  are included in the package `sane-frontends'.  Both packages
       can      be      downloaded      from      the      SANE       homepage
       (http://www.sane-project.org/).   Information about other frontends and
       backends can also be found on the SANE homepage.

GENERAL INFORMATION
       The following sections provide short descriptions  and  links  to  more
       information  about  several  aspects  of SANE.  A name with a number in
       parenthesis (e.g.  `sane-dll(5)') points to a manual page. In this case
       `man    5    sane-dll'    will   display   the   page.   Entries   like
       `/usr/share/doc/libsane/sane.tex' are references  to  text  files  that
       were     copied     to     the     SANE     documentation     directory
       (/usr/share/doc/libsane/) during installation. Everything else is a URL
       to a resource on the web.

       SANE homepage
         Information on all aspects of SANE including a tutorial and a link to
         the   SANE   FAQ   can   be   found    on    the    SANE    homepage:
         http://www.sane-project.org/.

       SANE device lists
         The  SANE  device  lists contain information about the status of SANE
         support for a specific device. If your scanner is  not  listed  there
         (either supported or unsupported), please contact us. See section HOW
         CAN YOU HELP SANE for details. There are lists for specific  releases
         of  SANE,  for  the  current development version and a search engine:
         http://www.sane-project.org/sane-supported-devices.html.   The  lists
         are also installed on your system at /usr/share/doc/libsane/.
```